# お気に入りではない質問の星アイコンのツールチップが、お気に入り用のものになっている

Tags: バグ, 却下

[image: これはお気に入りの質問です]

これは英語版でもバグっているようです: `This is a favorite question (click again to undo)` と表示されます。

Comment: 英語では意味合いが微妙です。それがわざっとなら、日本語の翻訳の改善をおすすめしますが、意味合いの目的を現在確認中。